# How to create a firm link in latest APFS

Tags: apfs, macos-catalina

I'm running the macOS beta for Catalina (10.15) and I'm trying to find out how to create a *firm link*. (Not a hard link, soft link, alias or anything like that.) The WWDC keynote mentions a new feature referred to as firm links but I can't seem to find out how to do it...

Comment: `man synthetic.conf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: you cannot [*at least not yet on Betas*]

From Apple's official Q/A

> Question: Can firmlinks be created by endusers, or are they reserved
> to the system? If they can be created by the enduser, what commands
> are used to create them?
>
> Answer: No, firmlinks can't be created by endusers. This is
> reserved currently to the system. There will be synthetic firmlinks
> coming, which can be used as mount points for network resources.
>
> Question: If firmlinks can be created by endusers, is there
> any advantage to using firmlinks over using Unix symlinks?
>
> Answer: Firmlinks can't be created by endusers. Symlinks will be more flexible because they are path-based and able to point to that
> path regardless of volume ID changes. Firmlinks will be referring to a
> particular volume.

reference:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117521

Comment: Well, now that Catalina is out it would be /great/ if they explained how to do synthetic firmlinks since otherwise you can't have folders on the root of the drive. :-/

Comment: @Jordan Try `man synthetic.conf`

Comment: @steshaw Thanks, you save my life. @Jordan for example `echo -e "data\t/Volumes/HDD" | sudo tee -a /etc/synthetic.conf` note that each line **should be separated by a tab** character, space can not work.

Comment: There's a problem with synthetic.conf, though: it only really works properly with links to directories in pre-existing (i.e. default macOS) paths. So if you want to firmlink e.g. `/home` & `/Users`, or `/mnt` & `/private/mnt`, it's OK, because both `/Users` & `/private` pre-exist. However, if you link `/home` & `/System/Volumes/Data/home`, then it's a new directory you need to create, and then macOS' FSEvents will broadcast a false path for file events in that directory, namely `/home` instead of `/System/Volumes/Data/home`, which can lead to serious problems. It seems Apple messed up here.